# PHP Page Blank - Not understanding scopes

Tags: php, variables, composer-php, medoo

So, simply put, I feel like this code should work. Literally at this moment I am just trying to create a PHP class that takes in some information and runs a command against the database.  I know the command works so it's not that, it something to do with the scope of my variables.

I'm new to PHP, and it's been interesting to handle.

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../bin/composer/vendor/autoload.php';

$cx = new Customer();
$cx->WriteCxToDB();

class Customer {
  public $database = new medoo([
    'database_type'=>'mysql',
    'database_name'=>'dbname',
    'server'=>'localhost',
    'username'=>'dbusername',
    'password'=>'dbpassword',
    'charset'=>'utf8'
  ]);

  public function WriteCxToDB(){
    global $database;
    if($database->has("customer", [
      "OR"=>[
        "username"=>"cxusername",
        "email"=>"email@gmail.com"
      ]
      ]))
      {
      echo "User already exists";
    }else{
      $database->insert("customer", [
        "username"=>"username",
        "keyword"=>"keyword",
        "email"=>"email@gmail.com",
        "phone"=>"444-444-4444",
        "first_name"=>"First",
        "last_name"=>"Last"
    ]);
    echo "User added";
  }
  echo "Done";
  }
}
?>
```

I am using composer and medoo to do this database entry.  I know the database code works because I've ran it on it's own and it runs fine.

What I'm struggling with the seems to be the variable `$database` in the code. The function call works if I remove that variable from the mix.  I feel like I'm just not understanding where I am supposed to declare the variable / how to reference it from within / outside the function.  Thanks.

Comment: Whenever you get a blank page in PHP when some output is otherwise expected, check your error logs. Enable display_errors always when developing and testing code - any fatal error should show up immediately. At the top of your script: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I notice you've used `global $database` but you also have a `$database` attribute defined in the class, which would be accessible as `$this->database`...

Comment: Instantiating a class instance `$database` when declaring a property does not appear to be one of the examples given at http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php so I would imagine your error reporting is turned off so you need to either turn it on or check your error logs.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments.  All of this helped a ton.  I'll go enable error reporting now, and maybe I won't have to ask another question in the future.  (wishful thinking)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the previous example you should be using something like this and pass a db connection into the class, extending a base class would allow reuse of the db connection:

```
private $database;  

public function __construct($db_connection = null){
    //do stuff or set db
    $this->database = $this->db_connect;
}
```

OR make a method in the class to do it

```
 private function db_connect(){
        return new medoo([
        // required
        'database_type' => 'mysql',
        'database_name' => 'name',
        'server' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'your_username',
        'password' => 'your_password',
        'charset' => 'utf8',    
        ]);

    }
```

to check consider catching the errors. Using a unique or primary key on the DB would be a safer way of doing this otherwise you have to do validation and searching on the DB.  Add the keys and check for duplicate errors.

```
if($database->error()){
  //deal with return or pass to logging
}
```

Comment: Thanks - creating the constructor seemed to make things work better and I was able to get this working.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is the use of global scope. Instead of:

```
 global $database;
    if($database->has("customer",
```

use

```
 if($this->database->has("customer",
```

you could also consider instantiating $database in the constructor, i.e.

```
private $database;

public function __construct() { 
  $this->database = new medoo([args....
```